# Configuring PyQt for IDEs

Tags: pycharm, pyqt4, python-idle

I have installed Qt and PyQt in ubuntu. It has been installed with the Python2 interpreter and not with Python3 interpreter. I can tell this by writing in **Terminal** `python` and then entering `from PyQt4 import QtGui`, and it imports successfully and but gives a ModuleNotFound error with `python3`.

The problem I am facing is that PyQt4 cannot be detected in any IDEs like IDLE or Pycharm. I think it may be some path error but I have no idea how to rectify this problem. I am new to this stuff and have been struggling with PyQt for quite some time. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** As the python2.7 was working fine in terminal, I tried installing IDLE2 which actually worked. But the problem with Pycharm is still unfixed. 
I changed the interpreter to `Python2.7` and saw these packages:
[image]
When I tried to add packages from the 'green plus button', I got this error while installing any of these packages: sip, qt, pyqt4, pyqt5:

```
Collecting PyQt4
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4
```

Comment: The IDEs that python are using?

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned IDLE and Pycharm doesn't recognise this module.

Comment: I find it strange, I use pycharm and if I establish the right interpreter, I can use it correctly. Have you established python2 as an interpreter in pycharm?

Comment: @eyllanesc It was a great idea. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: that python2 is not the same one that is shown when you use the terminal and you type python2, the path must be /usr/bin/python2

Comment: As you said, I already tried this. The list includes python3.6, python3, python2.7, python2, python. Setting python2 or python or python2.7 sets the interpreter as python2.7 (this is what is displayed after selecting it and pressing ok). Similarly python3 or python3.6 sets python3 as interpreter. So I checked /usr/bin/python-config,python2-config,python2.7-config which all shows the version as "2.7". As expected, python3-config showed version 3.6.

Comment: Chances are the python interpretor set as default in your terminal isn't inside the list. Try going to your terminal, and enter something like `import sys` `sys.path` and see where the folders are. On the right side of the list box in pycharm is a gear symbol, click that and select add local, locate the folder above, search for a python.exe, and add that.